# Retrieve the source code of request object

Tags: python, django

For the curiosity, I test within a CBV by adding print statement:

```
def post(self, request, block_id):
    sf = inspect.getsourcefile(request)
    code = inspect.getsouce(request)
```

However, I got the error:

```
 TypeError: <WSGIRequest: POST '/article/create/1'> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object.
```

`Request` is an object but it prompts that none of a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object.

How does this happen?

Comment: It's an *instance*, you want the source code of the *class*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get module source code by a python 'object' of that module? (not inspect.getsource)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759459/how-to-get-module-source-code-by-a-python-object-of-that-module-not-inspect)

Comment: interesting, instance is also a code object. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply: `inspect.getsource()` and `inspect.getsourcefile()` check their first argument's type and raise a `TypeError` if it's neither  a module (instance of the `module` class), a class (instance of the `type` class), method (instance of the `instancemethod` type), function (instance of the `function` class), traceback (instance of the `traceback` type), etc etc... FWIW those limitations are clearly documented:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> help(inspect.getsource)

Help on function getsource in module inspect:

getsource(object)
    Return the text of the source code for an object.

    The argument may be a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame,
    or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
    IOError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved.
```

Your `request` object is none of those, so `inspect` refuses it by raising a `TypeError`, which makes senses since it only can get the source code for something that does have a source code component.

If you want the source code for the `WSGRequest` **class**, you have to pass the class itself:

```
def post(self, request, block_id):
    sf = inspect.getsourcefile(type(request))
    code = inspect.getsouce(type(request))
```